# How do I run a shell script that is inside a package?

Tags: python, python-importlib

I have a .pyz of a Python package.  It contains a shell script, say `foo.sh`. I am trying to write a Python script that extracts the shell script from its package and run it through `subprocess.run`.

This is what I have:

```
from importlib import resources
for s in resources.contents(__package__):
    if s == 'foo.sh':
        subprocess.run(...)
```

How do I get the path of foo.sh to be passed to `subprocess.run`?

Comment: Do you already know the path of `foo.sh`? (like where it is within the package).

Comment: It's is in a subdirectory called `scripts`.